# Как нарисовать 9-ти конечную звезду на turtle?

Tags: python, turtle

Как нарисовать 9-ти конечную звезду на turtle?

[image: Пример]

Comment: точно так же, как и восьмиконечную, только с девятью концами.

Comment: я хз как(помогите пж

Comment: читай документацию, ищи примеры. за тебя никто делать не будет

Comment: @strawdog да ладно, уже сделал, у меня валялся исходник похожий)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```py
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
star = turtle.Turtle()

star.penup()
star.goto(-100, 0)
star.pendown()
star.speed(2) 

for _ in range(9):
    star.forward(100) 
    star.right(160)
    
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!